# DQN: Access to raw observations after conversion of observation space into a Box environment?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, dqn, openai-api

I'm adapting the Pytorch code from Tabor's course on DQNs (https://github.com/philtabor/Deep-Q-Learning-Paper-To-Code) to work with the vizdoomgym library, having previously managed to make a version work in TF.

After training my agent, I will visualize it's performance as an .mp4 video. Previously, I used the SK-video library to record the agent at play, as the in-house Monitor class did not work with the VZDgym library. This was achieved by simply saving each observation into an image array.

I have encountered a problem, as the code I am following invokes wrappers in order to convert the observation space into a Box environment, the images are in effect distorted as a result. These wrappers can be found in the utils.py file, with the main method shown below:

```
def make_env(env_name, shape=(84,84,1), repeat=4, clip_rewards=False,
             no_ops=0, fire_first=False):
    env = gym.make(env_name)
    env = RepeatActionAndMaxFrame(env, repeat, clip_rewards, no_ops, fire_first)
    env = PreprocessFrame(shape, env)
    env = StackFrames(env, repeat)

    return env
```

I notice that the preprocessing wrappers inherit the *observation* method, meaning that I should be able to access the observations and store them prior to preprocessing. However, I am not familiar with the memory management issues with such a solution, if it is even feasible? An alternative approach would be to try and "restore" the observations from their distorted representations back into their original form, but that doesn't seem feasible.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, the preprocessing wrapper can be used to successfully save the frames prior to preprocessing functions into an image array.

This image array can then be converted into a .mp4 video using the sk-video library.
However, a separate version of the wrapper had to be built for this, due to the risk of memory overflow, so the method is not ideal.